# JS Discord buttons error : 'Cannot send empty message'

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

Hi I'm making a Javascript based Discord bot, and I really wanted to implement the new Discord Buttons feature, the problem is, even using the documentation examples, I get the same error, again and again :

```js
(node:6184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

Here is the code (I am using module.exports with separated files for each commands) :

```js
const { MessageButton } = require('discord-buttons')

module.exports = {
    name: 'invite',
    descritipion: 'test command',
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        let button = new MessageButton()
            .setStyle('url')
            .setURL('https://npmjs.com/discord-buttons')
            .setLabel('Click me !')

        await message.channel.send('Hey, I am powered by npm discord-buttons : https://npmjs.com/discord-buttons');
        await message.channel.send(button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just send a button on its own. Instead, try adding the button to the previous message so they both get sent in one message as shown below
[The official documentation for this is here](https://discord-buttons.js.org/constructors/messagebutton)

```js
// Replace these
const { MessageButton } = require('discord-buttons')
await message.channel.send('Hey, I am powered by npm discord-buttons : https://npmjs.com/discord-buttons');
await message.channel.send(button);

// With these
const { MessageButton, MessageActionRow } = require('discord-buttons')
await message.channel.send('Hey, I am powered by npm discord-buttons : https://npmjs.com/discord-buttons', {
    component: new MessageActionRow().addComponent(button)
});
```

Also, did you forget to initialize DiscordButtons? Do it when you initialize your discord bot

```js
// Where you initialized your discord bot
const bot = new Discord.Client()
// Add this line
require("discord-button")(bot)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this does not work. The embed get sent, but the button is still not.

Comment: Even with this change it does not work. I even tried to reinstall discord-buttons and it is not working as well. Although i get no more error it does not send anything

Comment: Ok Let me try that

Comment: New error 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: MessageActionRow is not defined' I think i have to define that but i don't know how.

Comment: import it from `discord-buttons`

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: It is still not sending it. I am using Better Discord but it has no impact on that aside. I don't know why it does not send it, because when i console.log the button, it is here.

Comment: so you're saying you see the message but not the button?

Comment: Yes I can the the NPM Embed with the message 'Hey, I am powered by npm discord-buttons : https://npmjs.com/discord-buttons' but not the button

Comment: what are the versions of your `discord.js` and `discord-buttons` packages?

Comment: ```"discord-buttons": "^3.2.1",
    "discord.js": "^12.5.3",`
```

Comment: check out the new answer

Comment: Ok let me try again

Comment: please mark it as correct so that others will know It is a solved issue :)